# JAVA Linked list constructor constatntly returns null

Tags: java, linked-list

I've been working on a `JAVA` character sequence (analogous to a string) implemented as a `Linked List`. Each `Node` in the list consists of three fields: `data` (i.e., what character it represents), `value` (i.e., how many times it is repeated in a row) and `next` (i.e., what node it is followed by).

One of the constructors "translates" a `String` into a `List` as such. However, it happens to always return a `null` `List`, as the output of the code

```
private static void StringToNode (String s, int i, int j, CharNode head){
    head = new CharNode(s.charAt(i), j, null);

    if (i + 1 < s.length() && s.charAt(i + 1) == s.charAt(i)){
        StringToNode(s, i + 1, j + 1, head);
    }
    else if (i + 1 < s.length() && s.charAt(i + 1) != s.charAt(i)){
        StringToNode(s, i + 1, 1, head.getNext());
    } 
}

public StringList(String s){
    if (s.length() == 0)
        _head = null;
    else
        StringToNode(s, 0, 1, _head);
    if (_head == null)
        System.out.println("Rats!");
}
```

is *rats*. I can't come up with any reason for this code to fail. So help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it needs to be `CharNode*` or `CharNode&` if you want to edit in place. I would recommend modifying `StringToNode` to return a CharNode instead as that is clearer to the user (i.e `_head = StringToNode(...)`

Comment: @RobertEkendahl it's in Java.

Comment: Were you expecting `StringToNode(s,0,1,_head)` to change `_head`?  Java passes parameters by value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: The `head` method parameter is being assigned to, but the change is not visible in the calling method because the `head` in `StringToNode()` is a copy of the reference of `_head` in the `StringList`  constructor.  Read about Java [passing by reference or value](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html).  Your `StringToNode` method should return the `CharNode` that it created.

Comment: Thank you all. Your remarks helped me track the problem.